# 8th gen iPad I want to go back to the original configuration after quick start

Tags: ipad, settings, ipados

I bought a new iPad for my wife. Here she doesn’t like it. So I did a quick start using my old iPad. She changed her mind. How do I go back to the original configuration
.

Answer (score 1):

To restore an iPad to factory settings, connect it to a computer running macOS 10.15 or later, or to a PC/Mac running iTunes. It will show up in Finder (or iTunes) from where you can initiate the restore.

Apple has it documented in detail in [Restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252).

If all you want is to run the setup assistant, open the settings app and in general, there is a reset all settings option.

[image: Erase all content and settings]

Choose “Erase all content and settings”